# How to get street address from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, addressbook

I need a contact's street address. I know how to get the single value properties, but the street address is a multivalue property. Apple's documentation shows how to set it, but not retrieve it. Any help?

PS: this does not work:

```
ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
```

Comment: If the edit you posted is the correct answer, you should post it as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figured it out:

```
ABMultiValueRef st = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(st) > 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(st, 0);
    self.street.text = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift version :

```
    if let addresses : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef? where ABMultiValueGetCount(addresses) > 0 {
        for index in 0..<ABMultiValueGetCount(addresses){
            if let address = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addresses, index)?.takeRetainedValue() as? [String:String],
                label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(addresses, index)?.takeRetainedValue()  as? String{
                    print("\(label): \(address) \n")
            }
        }
    }
```

You can access individual field of address by providing corresponding key :

```
let street  = address[kABPersonAddressStreetKey as String]
let city    = address[kABPersonAddressCityKey as String]
let state   = address[kABPersonAddressStateKey as String]
let zip     = address[kABPersonAddressZIPKey as String]
let country = address[kABPersonAddressCountryKey as String]
let code    = address[kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey as String]
```

Comment: it says `use of undeclared type 'ABMultiValueRef'` and `use of unresolved identifier ABMultiValueGetCount`

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

```
//Extract billing address from ABRecord format and assign accordingly
let addressProperty: ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(billingAddress, kABPersonAddressProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as ABMultiValue

if let dict: NSDictionary = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressProperty, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? NSDictionary {
     print(dict[String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey)] as? String)
     print(dict[String(kABPersonAddressCityKey)] as? String)
     print(dict[String(kABPersonAddressStateKey)] as? String)
     print(dict[String(kABPersonAddressZIPKey)] as? String)
     print(dict[String(kABPersonAddressCountryKey)] as? String) //"United States"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user has multiple addressed defined - work, home, etc, you will need to use the identifier attribute to distinguish between them.  What I have arrive at, culled from similar posts on email addresses, is:

```
#pragma mark - ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate

- (IBAction)chooseContact:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
//    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void) peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    if (property == kABPersonAddressProperty)
    {
        ABMultiValueRef addresses = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        CFIndex addressIndex = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(addresses, identifier);
        CFDictionaryRef address = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addresses, addressIndex);

        // create address string to lookup
        NSString *street = (NSString*) CFDictionaryGetValue(address, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
        NSString *city = (NSString*) CFDictionaryGetValue(address, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
        NSString *state = (NSString*) CFDictionaryGetValue(address, kABPersonAddressStateKey);
        NSString *postal = (NSString*) CFDictionaryGetValue(address, kABPersonAddressZIPKey);
        NSString *country = (NSString*) CFDictionaryGetValue(address, kABPersonAddressCountryKey);

        CFRelease(address);
        CFRelease(addresses);
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should work like this (derived from the documentation, not tested):

```
ABMultiValueRef addressMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
CFArrayRef allAddresses = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(addressMultiValue);
CFDictionaryRef firstAddress = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allAddresses, 0);
CFStringRef street = CFDictionaryGetValue(firstAddress, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
NSLog(@"%@", (__bridge NSString *)street);
CFRelease(allAddresses);
CFRelease(addressMultiValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Address Book UI framework is deprecated in iOS 9. Use the APIs defined in the ContactsUI framework instead. To learn more, see [ContactsUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui).